# Excel IF + AND + Date range formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am looking to create and IF function that does the following.

There is a ton of data with one column containing dates. I want and if functions that labels each row according to the following.

If date falls between 0-30 days of todays date in the past then label "GOOD" (so if todays date is 21/09/2017 then it should be labelled as "GOOD" should it falls between the dates 21/09/2017 and 21/08/2017)

If date falls between 31-60 days of todays date in the past then label "FAIR"

If date falls between 61-90 days of todays date in the past then label "ATTENTION"

If date falls between 91+ days of todays date in the past then label "CLEARANCE"

Hope someone can help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
=IF(TODAY()-A2<31,"Good",IF(TODAY()-A2<61,"Fair",IF(TODAY()-A2<91,"Attention","Clearance")))
```

[image]

`Column D` shows the difference between today date and cell date.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Answer

Use VLOOKUP to potentially ease your future formula maintenance.  In an unused location, set up a table that has your break point ranges and associated return values.  For this example I used the following:

[image: Lookup Table]

Technically speaking column G is not required, but it can be easier for some people to read.

Now assuming your dates are in Column A, you can use the following formula in B2 copying down:

```
=TODAY()-A2
```

and in C2 use the following look up formula and copy down to get your desired results:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$3:$H$6,3,1)
```

now if you are not keen on generating the extra column for calculate the number of days, you can substitute that first formula into the second to get:

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY()-A2,$F$3:$H$6,3,1)
```

place the above in B2 instead and copy down.

The following is an example of the first approach:

[image: POC]

The main advantage to this approach is you can manipulate the lookup table easily changing breakpoints, wording of results etc easily without touching your formula (when done right)

if you have the potential for negative days, instead of returning an error, you could wrap the lookup formula in an IFERROR function to give a custom message or result.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$F$3:$H$6,3,1),"In the Future")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts with A2, A3 and so on.. as below

[image]

Apply the below formula in B2 and drag down up to A8

```
=IF(AND(--TEXT(TODAY()-A2,"@@")>=-1,--TEXT(TODAY()-A2,"@")<30),"GOOD",IF(AND(--TEXT(TODAY()-A2,"@@")>=30,--TEXT(TODAY()-A2,"@")<60),"FAIR",IF(AND(--TEXT(TODAY()-A2,"@@")>=60,--TEXT(TODAY()-A2,"@")<90),"ATTENTION",IF(--TEXT(TODAY()-A2,"@@")>90,"CLEARANCE","FUTURE DATES"))))
```